# how do i get that date with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get between `Last Backup:` and the ending `span`

but I'm getting blank value?

```
string test = @">Last Backup: 4/27/13</span></";

string regex = @"(?<=Last Backup: )*.(?='</span')";

var match = Regex.Match(test, regex);

Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: Why does `regex` have single quotes around `'</span'`?

Comment: Great question! it didn't belong there. when I took it out I got the match thanks.

Comment: @Jon-Eric convert your comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `(?<=Last Backup: ).*(?=\</span)`

Errors :

- you have inverted `.*`
- you have put `'` around `</span`